# How to deal with main and master in Github

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch

I have opened a Git repository with readme file in Github, and then use below to push local code to this repository

```
git push origin master
```

It shows two branchs: main and master, but with git branch, it only shows main branch

```
$ git branch
* main
```

As main branch is empty, I use below to force the commit to main

```
git push --force origin main
```

Now there are two same branches: main and master in the repository, but still with git branch, only show *main.

When I clicked the master, it shows:

```
This branch is even with main.
```

I use below to delete master, but the error as below:

```
$ git push main --delete origin/master
fatal: 'main' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What should I do now to delete one of them?
And why the main not replaced by the master?
Later should I use git push origin main instead of master to push changes?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this from the UI, you can go to the branches section of the repository and delete the branch you want to delete.

[image]

There is delete icon on right most side of a branch name.

[image]

If you want to do on git:

`git push origin --delete master`

The reason why you see only `main` in your local setup is, when you clone any repo only the default branch is cloned. For having other branch on git you have to `fetch` and `pull` the other branch.

For pushing changes after deleting master, you can use `git push origin main` to push changes in main branch.

Comment: thank you. 'git push origin --delete master' works, but as deleting from UI, is there any icon for deleting?

Comment: I added the icon.

Answer (score 2):

### Try this once it worked for me.

##### First

```
$ git branch -M main
```

It basically renames the master branch to main.

```
-M               move/rename a branch, even if target exists
```

---

##### Second

Force push the commit to main branch in remote repository.

```
$ git push -u -f origin main
```

===========================================================

###### This is output I got back.

```
$ git push -u -f origin main
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To https://github.com/roxylius/gdfgdfgdf.git
 + 2926bd4...35f720a main -> main (forced update)
branch 'main' set up to track 'origin/main'.
```

Answer (score 1):

This shows that
`main` is your master there is no other branches in your repo

```
$ git branch
* main
```

Try this if it works

```
git checkout master
git branch
```

You can delete a branch like this.
You must not be in that branch if are gonna delete it

```
git branch -D branch_name
```